# Users Unable to edit their profile

Tags: members, ee3, solspace-user, profile-edit

I am using the User module, and when logged in as a member, I am unable to see the user's profile while using the edit profile form. (Front-end)

The form does load, however the information contained on the form is all information from the Super Admin, not the signed in user.

I have tried the parameter `username="logged_in_user"` and that does not work.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Edit:
dynamic="no" still does not work, even with username="{username}" or username="{logged_in_username}"; Also, this was tried on an incognito browser, so even if I was logged in, it shouldn't have the option to pull the super admin account info.

EDIT2:

Actually found the solution: Turns out this form cannot be used in a partial, which was the problem.

Comment: We would need to see what your template code looks like and what your URL looks like before commenting further. :)

Comment: Actually figured out the problem, turns out it was in a partial, and that caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several things happening here.
It seems to think that you are still logged in as the administrator.
Log out, clear cache and cookies and try again. After logging in and out several times as different users can cross things up once in a while.

If you are going to hard code things, try setting:

username="{username}"
or
member_id="{member_id}"

and set dynamic="no"

Otherwise it should be getting the info from the currently logged in user.
Display that info somewhere else on the page so you can see who it thinks you are.

you can also put those things in the uri
username="{segment_3}"
or
member_id="{segment_3}"

Comment: Please see original post for edit regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

They key for the entire issue was that the form was being included using a partial.

The partial cannot parse the form on-the-fly like a template can.

This caused the issue.